# repository folder structure and sharing the eclipse IDE files for rebuilding

Tags: eclipse, version-control, build, repository, structure

I have a folder structure to a project in svn repository as below

--> executable

```
/trunk/proj_A
/trunk/proj_A/src
/trunk/proj_A/inc
/trunk/proj_A/build/win32/vs
/trunk/proj_A/build/win32/eclipse
/trunk/proj_A/build/linux
/trunk/proj_A/x_extern/ -> /trunk/proj_B, /trunk/proj_C, ...
```

--> Libraries follow the folder structure as

```
/trunk/proj_B
/trunk/proj_B/src
/trunk/proj_B/inc
/trunk/proj_B/build/win32/vs
/trunk/proj_B/build/win32/eclipse
/trunk/proj_B/build/linux
```

So far i was using visual studio IDE to build the project and maintain the IDE files at the location build/win32/vs in repository. src, inc for code, build folder to store IDE related files or makefiles based on platform.

Visual studio is some what good in drawing a separate line between IDE's folder hierarchy for building and actual file system hierarchy for version control (dictated by repository folder structure) which made life easier.

I am trying to migrate to eclipse IDE with the same expectations in mind about version control and IDE's folder hierarchy. But all my efforts are blocked due to below two  issues.

1. eclipse IDE related files like .project, .cproject, .settings cannot be located any other sub-folder other than project root.
2. If sub folder(build/win32/eclipse) is kept as project root and other folders (../../../src, ../../../inc) are accessed using linked folders, then eclipse do not identify the linked folder contents as version controlled.

Due to the two issues i am not able to use eclipse IDE just like i was maintaining IDE related files in my version control in simple manner.

So My questions are

1. Are the above two issues are limitations of eclipse IDE? If not What is the way out?
2. Any other recommendations to migrate to eclipse without drastically changing  my repository folder structure and still share the IDE files for rebuilding? Is this possible?